# Trouble finding an infinite series for these iterations...

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following iteration, which first I want to get a general form for "$p$" terms, and then I want to put it into a sum.

$$E_1 = \frac{e}{a^2} - \frac{e}{(2a)^2} + \frac{e}{(3a)^2} - ... \frac{e}{(pa)^2}$$

$$E_2 = \frac{e}{a^2} - \frac{e}{(a)^2} + \frac{e}{(2a)^2} - ... \frac{e}{((p-1)a)^2}$$

$$E_3 = \frac{e}{(2a)^2} - \frac{e}{(a)^2} + \frac{e}{(a)^2} - \frac{e}{(2a)^2} + \frac{e}{(3a)^2} - ... \frac{e}{((p-2)a)^2}$$

$$E_n = \textrm{???}$$

$$E = \sum_n^p \textrm{???}$$

Let me know if you need more terms, but I think you get the pattern. I've been stuck on this for a good 45 minutes and just can't figure it out. THanks!

Comment: How do you decide which terms have 'a' in the numerator?

Comment: Sorry I just fixed that typo right as u posted =p, they're all e's

Comment: Have you considered factoring out the common term as a starting point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E_1 = -\frac{e}{a^2}\sum_{n=1}^p {\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}}$$
$$E_2 = +\frac{e}{a^2}\sum_{n=2}^{p-1} {\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}} $$
$$\ldots$$
$$E_m = (-1)^m\frac{e}{a^2}\sum_{n=m}^{p-m} {\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}} $$
Also note that if you define the above as $E_{m,p}$, you have:
$$E_{m,p} = E_{1,p} - E_{1,p-m-1}+E_{1,m-1}$$
So, if you know what $E_1$ is (say by using [some complicated zeta function relation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%5B%28-1%29%5En/n%5E2,%7Bn,1,p%7D%5D)), you can also find $E_m$.

$$ $$
Now, what exactly do you want to sum?

Comment: Well I neeeded to find an expression for total force on an object (the $m$th object) from an electric field, so it looks like I can find it from what you have provided, thanks!